# What algebraic structure, if any, is determined by a uniquely left-solvable semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

By *uniquely left-solvable semigroup* I mean a set $\mathcal{S}$ with a mapping $f:\mathcal{S}\times\mathcal{S}\to\mathcal{S}$, represented by juxtaposition $f\left(a,b\right)\equiv{ab},$ such that $\forall_{a,b,c}\left(ab\right)c=a\left(bc\right),$ and $\forall_{a,b}\underline{\exists}_x xa=b.$  Here the notation $\underline{\exists}_x$ is to be read *there exists **exactly one** $x$*.  *Right-solvable* would mean $\forall_{a,b}\exists_x ax=b.$  Right-solvability is neither asserted nor precluded.

I believe this will prove to be an Abelian group, but I have not yet shown it to be so.  I am still working on it.

This is completely for my own edification, and is not a homework problem, nor an exercise given in a book or other lesson.  I simply find the question interesting, and would like to share it.

Comment: Indeed it defines a group, but why would you think it is abelian ?

Comment: In physics the method is known by the acronym SWAG.  I'm sticking my neck out.

Comment: Every group - abelian or not - satisfies those axioms.

Comment: @CaptainLama Why does it define a group, always? I don't see, for example, why an identity element exists: while each $a$ has a unique $i_a$ with $i_aa=a$, I see no reason why $i_a=i_b$ should hold in general.

Comment: It is indeed not necessarily a group: for instance, you could have $ab=a$ for all $a,b$.

Comment: You are right, it seemed to me that it should be a group, but I did not think about it enough. I mainly wanted to emphasize that commutativity was not to be expected.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see.  This is a constant function.  If it were numerical, and $\{a,b,x\}$ were plotted in Cartesian coordinates, we would have a horizontal line $\{a,b,b\}$.  In order to have an inverse, the solution function has to be monotonic and everywhere non-constant in both arguments.  I'm sure there is a more general way of seeing this.  If you care to post an answer explaining why your example contradicts my proposition, I will accept it. (Assuming as I do, it will be a correct and helpful answer.)  If not,, I will try to come up with my own explanation,  Which may not be has coherent.

Comment: I think this is a bit stronger than a right-cancellable semigroup; certainly these conditions define a right-cancellable semigroup, since $xa=ya$ implies $x=y$ for all $a$ (by uniqueness of the solution). However, if we let $X$ be an infinite set, and let $S$ be the collection of all surjections $f\colon X\to X$, which a semigroup under composition, then the resulting semigroup is right-cancellable, but does not satisfy your condition. Just take an $a$ that takes the same value on two points $x_1\neq x_2$, and a $b$ that takes different values on them; then $xa=b$ has no solution.

Comment: “Monotonic” does not make sense in the absence of an order, so I’m not sure what you mean by saying that “the solution function has to be monotonic”. Even where order makes sense, the answer need not be monotonic; e.g., in the integers modulo 4 under addition, with $a=2$, and order $0\lt 1\lt 2\lt 3$, the solutions to $xa=b$, in order, are $2$, $3$, $0$, $1$ which is not a monotonic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition does not define a group. Given any nonempty set $S$ with more than one element, define the product as $ab = a$ for all $a,b\in S$. This is a semigroup, and in this semigroup, the equation $xa=b$ has the unique solution $x=b$ for all $a$ and $b$; yet because $S$ has more than one element but every element is idempotent ($bb=b$ for all $b$), it cannot be a group.

(The comment that you hope it would define an abelian group is also incorrect, since any group satisfies the condition, abelian or not.)

As to whether this condition defines a specific, known class of semigroups, I don’t know (I’m not a semigroup theorist), but I can tell that it is a subclass of right-cancellable semigroups (semigroups in which $xa=ya$ implies $x=y$), but is not equal to the full class. Right cancellability follows by the uniqueness condition of the solution (in fact, saying “every equation has a unique solution” is equivalent to saying every equation has a solution *and* we have right-cancellability). However, there are right-cancellable semigroups that do not satisfy the condition, because not all such equations have solutions.

For a concrete example, let $X$ be an infinite set, and consider the subsemigroup of $T_X$ (the full transformation semigroup of all function $X\to X$ under composition) given by the surjective functions. This is a subsemigroup, since the composition of surjective functions is surjective. In addition, since surjective functions have right inverses/are right cancellable, this is a right-cancellable semigroup. However, not every equation $xa=b$ has a solution. For example, taking $b$ to be the identity, $xa=b$ has a solution if and only if $a$ is invertible (i.e., a bijection), so taking any non-injective surjection for $a$ gives an equation with no solution in this semigroup.